# vba: print inverted commas string in a file

Tags: vba

I have to write a string in a txt file:

```
Option Explicit
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
filename1 = "OutputHtml.txt"
Open path & "\" & filename1 For Output As #1
Print #1, "<table class="msg">"
```

but `Print #1, "<table class="msg">"` is automatically compiled in `Print #1, "<table class="; msg; ">"` and it show me: *msg variable not defined*.

how can i print the right string into filename1? Thanks in advance

Comment: double " escapes a " so `"<table class=""msg"">"` or simply use a single quote which is fine for HTML `"<table class='msg'>"` and makes things simpler.

Comment: and if i would write this: "<tr class="msg-log">" which "log" is a string variable? Print #1, "<tr class=""msg-" & strLog "> " ?

Comment: `"<tr class=""msg-" & logStr & """>" `